# Ember : Modify dinamically classNameBindings to activate error css

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

I'm trying to change css class of an input text field to reflect an error . Just painting border in red .

I have created the following component :

**app/templates/components**

```
<div id="echo-hlabel-tf">
<span id="{{id}}-echo-hlabel-tf-label" 
      class="{{class}}-echo-hlabel-tf-hlabel">
        {{label}}
</span>
<span id="{{id}}-echo-hlabel-tf-value" 
      class="{{class}}-echo-hlabel-tf-value">
        {{input type="text" id='input-id' class='input-class' 
                value=textValue
                focus-out = (action 'validateRegExp' textValue regExp) 
                key-up = (action 'showText' textValue)}}
</span>
```

and his controller **app/components/echo-label-tf.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNameBindings:['regExpError'],
    regExpError:false,


actions: {
    validateRegExp(text,regExpStr,event){
        let regExpObj = new RegExp(regExpStr)
        if(regExpObj.test(text)){
            alert('entry matches')
        }else{
            this.set('regExpError',true)
        }
    },
    showText(text){
        if(text == 'Santiago'){
            alert('This is your name');
        }
    }
}
});
```

with the idea of using it this way :

**app/templates/programmers.hbs**

```
<div>
   {{echo-hlabel-tf 
       id= "id-test-hlabel"
       class="class-test-hlabel-mio"
       label="Horizontal textfield"
       textValue="..." 
       regExp="^([a-z0-9]{5})$"
   }}
</div>
```

As the text changes, and we focus out from the input box, it fires the event **validateRegExp**, and , if text doesn't match with regular expression , it changes **regExpError** to true .

I guess it should update **classNameBindings** and add the class **regExpError**, but it's not working . It doesn't add the class, even when regExpError is true .

On the other hand, I have studied the possibility of changing the action 'validateRegExp' to a **ember.computed attribute** . This way ...

** app/components/echo-label-tf.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNameBindings:['regExpError'],

    regExpError:Ember.computed('textValue','regExpStr',function(){
    let regExpObj = new RegExp(regExpStr)
    if(!regExpObj.test(textValue)){
            return true;
    }
    return false;
   }),

  actions: {

    showText(text){
        if(text == 'Santiago'){
            alert('This is your name');
        }
    }

}
```

});

But in this case , even I think it's the right way of achieving my goal, I have a lot of doubts . How do I have to modify the component template and the outter template to pass the arguments 'textValue' and 'regExpStr' to the ember computed element ? and when is this code fired up ? .

I know that there are two questions in one, but I'm trying to find the best way to do this .

Answer (score 0):

Ok . At the end, I solved my problem . I have created an ember twiddle to show the result . Now, when you don't enter five characters to textfield, it turns red . Allthough, if you enter five characters, it turns white .

https://ember-twiddle.com/72003d7484b513d3126ef11a7bc5262d?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs

Thanks anyway

Comment: what is the difference between your twiddle and your question?.  which one is exactly solved your problem. Actually, I looked into your code I didn't find any issue.

Comment: Indeed , both are almost the same . One option , that I think was the root of my problem, was a bad css class  inside the css file ( I didn't show this in the question . Sorry ).Not a good reference for the input field, with .error in front of it . Or, maybe I had some issues refreshing the page and the component in the navigator  that suddenly, I solved. I don't know .

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Hope it helped ;)